# Enforce function parameter must be optional

Tags: swift, option-type

I have a custom operator ?= that is used to simply assign optional values to non-optionals.

```
var a: String
let b: String?

a = b ?? a
// is simplified to
a ?= b
```

This works well, but I don't want people to be able to use this operator when `b` is not optional. It's not going to cause any problems but it looks bad and I don't like it.

My function signature is currently:

```
func ?=<T> (originalValue: inout T, optionalNewValue: T?)
```

How could I make this cause a compiler warning or error when optionalNewValue is not actually an optional?

Comment: 1) Why would you want to limit what the right side can be? What if I want to replace `a` with another optional, `b`, if `a` is `nil`?

Comment: 2) This operator isn't actually as useful as it might seem, because such an operator doesn't have the power to change the type of the left operand to make it not optional. This was previously suggested ([0024-optional-value-setter](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0024-optional-value-setter.md)), and rejected ([rational](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution-announce/2016-February/000043.html))

Comment: @Alexander Hmm, good point. I should specify more clearly that I don't want to allow `b` to be nonoptional.

Comment: @Alexander I read the suggestion you linked and though it's similar, it's actually the opposite of what I'm trying to do here. I'm not trying to make `a` nonoptional by providing a fallback value; I'm trying to set `a` to equal `b` if `b` exists, and fall back to `a` if it doesn't.

Comment: Ah. I see, it's similar, but kinda reversed. But honestly, I'm still skeptical of the value of this. It's kind of "opposite" to what people expect from experience with `??` (where the right side is the "fall back" value).

Comment: Yeah, it's not the clearest choice of operator but I couldn't think of a better one. The intention is just to simplify cases like `kindaLongVariableName = someOtherValue ?? kindaLongVariableName` which gets irritating to write and to read after a while.

Comment: I'm a bit suspicious of the `x = y ?? x` pattern, though, particularly if it is occurring often enough that it is irritating you. It suggests a deeper problem that is possibly resolved with a better type rather than a fancier operator. When does this occur? I've encountered the situation that @Alexander notes several times, but I've never encountered this one.

Comment: @RobNapier I have you in my head as "The type guy". I love it! :P

Comment: @RobNapier the first case to hand is `aLabel.textColor = dataSource.specialTextColor ?? aLabel.textColor`

Comment: That feels like you're storing model information (the correct color) in the view (the label). That doesn't seem right. I would think that dataSource should have default values, so that it returns the correct `textColor` and you just assign it in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other have said in the comments, the `?=` operator might not be the best solution to your problems. Now if you're keen to that operator, or adds value to your code base, then there is a workaround that would allow you to reject non optional values on the right hand side of the operator.

You can use an `OptionalCompatible` protocol for the right hand side of the operator:

```
protocol OptionalCompatible {
    associatedtype Wrapped
    var optionalValue: Wrapped? { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalCompatible {
    var optionalValue: Wrapped? { return self }
}

func ?=<T, U> (originalValue: inout T, optionalNewValue: U) where U: OptionalCompatible, U.Wrapped == T {
    originalValue = optionalNewValue.optionalValue ?? originalValue
}
```

Using a custom protocol will disable the auto-promotion of non-optionals to optionals, allowing only optionals to be used.

There is a caveat, though: in theory the conformance `OptionalCompatible` can be added to any type.

Answer (score 1):

> How could I make this cause a compiler warning or error when optionalNewValue is not actually an optional?

You cannot. It is a built-in fact of Swift that a nonOptional of type T can always be assigned or passed where an `Optional<T>` is expected.